# PHP - Mantener información global común a todas las sesiones

Tags: php

Buenas,

Estoy desarrollando una web en PHP donde necesito guardar información a nivel de aplicación, para que una vez guardado el objeto esté disponible para todas las sesiones y cualquier petición haga uso de ello.

He probado usando una variable estática dentro de una clase, pero en peticiones diferentes pierde el valor almacenado. También he probado con $_GLOBALS, pero ocurre lo mismo.

¿Alguien me podría echar una mano? Seguro que es una tontería, pero no doy con ello.

Un saludo y muchas gracias,

PD: Siempre podría guardarlo en un fichero o en BDD, pero es lo que estoy intentando evitar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que estás buscando es caché. Tienes varias alternativas:

1. Guardarlo en un archivo, file-cache
2. Guardarlo en una base de datos (sql, redis, mongo)
3. Utilizar memcache http://php.net/manual/es/memcache.add.php
4. APC http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-add.php
5. XCache http://xcache.lighttpd.net/

Comment: Buenas. He estado intentando hacer funcionar alguno de los métodos pero no lo consigo, ya que me indica que no encuentra las clases y demás. Estoy usando Symfony, pero no puedo usar la Cache incluida en la versión 3, puesto que necesitaría versión php>7 y en el servidor que tengo la versión instalada es la 5.6.30. ¿Me podrías echar una mano con esto? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Debes instalar la extensión en cada caso, ya que por lo general no vienen por defecto en una instalación de php. Según tu servidor se hará de un modo u otro. En debian por ejemplo sería: apt-get install php-memcache php-apcu para instalar APC y memcache.

Comment: El problema está en que en el servidor compartido no es posible hacer instalación de componentes, por lo que tendría que ser algo dinámicamente cargable por la aplicación Symfony.

Comment: Symfony hace uso de esas extensiones y de más métodos para realizar caché, puedes revisar los distintos métodos que utiliza y encontrar uno a tu medida: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache.html. Quizás puedas utilizar filecache, algo que en principio no querías :(

Comment: Al final he implementado yo un volcado a fichero, y antes de ponerlo en producción lo cambiaré por un sistema un poco más complejo. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.